# How can I create empty folder inside GCP Cloud Storage bucket using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I have a bucket `my-bucket-101` inside it I have categories folder in which want to create 200 folders representing categories, initially those would be empty.

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

const bucketName = 'my-bucket-101';

export async function addFolder(folderName) {
  const storage = new Storage({ keyFilename: './key.json' });
  const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
  const resp = bucket.upload('', {destination: `categories/${folderName}`, (err, file) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(`${err}`);
    }
    console.log(file);
  });

  console.log(`Resp from bucket.upload: ${resp}`);
  console.log(`Folder created inside coaches: ${folderName}`);
}
```

When I upload it says - 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, open'

I know this may be because of empty string I'm passing in upload method, but I don't know other method to create empty folder in GCS.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by uploading a test file

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

const bucketName = 'my-bucket-101';

export function addFolder(folderName: string) {
    const storage = new Storage({ keyFilename: './key.json' });
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
    bucket.upload('test.json', { destination: `categories/${folderName}/` }, (err, file) => {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err.message);
        }
        console.log(file);
    });
    console.log(`Folder "${folderName}" created in "categories/".`);
}
```

Comment: Folders do not exist in Cloud Storage. Your code did not create a folder. It created a file but no folders. All files exist in the root of the bucket. What you think is a folder is just characters that are part of the object name.

Comment: As for today - folders exist in GCS and can be nested.